# Is there a way of making the Unity editor paint decals on surfaces?

Tags: graphics, unity

I see other engines can do this, here's a video of what I would like to achieve :

[image]

I think the one on the image uses something that blends the surface and the image, but I just want to be able to paint a image on a surface.

How can I do this within the unity editor ? :)

---

Edit : Here's another video that kinda shows what I want to do. [(Click me)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHUJ44L4bgY)

(I want to code it myself, I don't want some kind of downloadable asset :P )

Answer (score 2):

The footage you have provided uses a vertex color blend method.
it's the same method used by most terrain systems.
you have to first have a custom shader that blends textures based on vertex colors
(u may find a couple of them via the internet or easily make one with node based shader editors like:
**Amplify shader editor**(paid), **Unity's builtin Shader graph**(Free, get it through package manager -still in beta phase-), or **shader forge**(Free, open source -works on older unity versions like 2017-)).

Then you have to paint on vertex color values via a script or just use some assets from the asset store.

Unity has a built-in tool called Polybrush, it's a multifunctional tool capable of both painting vertex colors and offsetting their position for sculpting meshes.
[Get Polybrush](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/painting/toz-vertex-painter-36688)
as it may be complex for the sake of reverse engineering there is a simpler tool you can take a look at:
[Get TOZ vertex painter](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/painting/toz-vertex-painter-36688)
and it's free too.

have a nice day!